# Solución de laberinto en java por anchura sin repetir casilla

Tags: java

Intento encontrar la solución a un laberinto por anchura pero me es imposible no repetir casilla o saltarme una restricción que es ir solo a los adyacentes. El programa tiene que estar obligatóriamente en Anchura, nada de profundidad.

```
public List<Coords> searchPathBFS(Coords from, Coords to){ 

boolean visitado[][] = new boolean[mazeSolver.length][mazeSolver[0].length];
List<Coords> MazeC= new LinkedList<Coords>(); //Lista de coordenadas a devolver
Queue<Coords> Q = new LinkedList<Coords>();  // Cola para el recorrido
boolean encontrado = false;

if(mazeSolver[from.row][from.column]==false){ 
    System.out.println("La casilla de inicio esta bloqueada");
    return null;
    }
    else if(mazeSolver[to.row][to.column]==false) {
        System.out.println("La casilla final esta bloqueada");
        return null;
        }
        else{

            Coords actual = from;
            MazeC.add(from);
            Q.offer(from);
            visitado[from.row][from.column]=true;

    //Recorrido en anchura
            while(!Q.isEmpty() && !encontrado){

                Coords celda=Q.poll();

                if(celda.row!=0) 
                    if(mazeSolver[celda.row-1][celda.column] && !visitado[celda.row-1][celda.column]){
                        visitado[celda.row-1][celda.column]=true;
                        Coords empilar= new Coords(celda.row-1,celda.column);

                        if(empilar.column==to.column && empilar.row==to.row){
                            MazeC.add(empilar);
                            encontrado=true;
                            System.out.println("he llegado aqui 4");
                            break;
                        }else{
                            Q.offer(empilar);
                            MazeC.add(empilar);

                        }
                    }

                if(celda.row!=mazeSolver.length-1)
                    if(mazeSolver[celda.row+1][celda.column] && !visitado[celda.row+1][celda.column]){

                        visitado[celda.row+1][celda.column]=true;
                        Coords empilar= new Coords(celda.row+1, celda.column);
                        if(empilar.column==to.column && empilar.row==to.row){
                            MazeC.add(empilar);
                            encontrado=true;
                            System.out.println("he llegado aqui 4");
                            break;

                        }else{
                            Q.offer(empilar);
                            MazeC.add(empilar);

                        }
                    }
                if(celda.column!=0)
                    if(mazeSolver[celda.row][celda.column-1] && !visitado[celda.row][celda.column-1]){
                        visitado[celda.row][celda.column-1]=true;
                        Coords empilar = new Coords(celda.row, celda.column-1);
                        if(empilar.column==to.column && empilar.row==to.row){
                            MazeC.add(empilar);
                            encontrado=true;
                            System.out.println("he llegado aqui 4");
                            break;
                        }else{
                            Q.offer(empilar);
                            MazeC.add(empilar);

                        }
                    }
                if(celda.column!= mazeSolver[0].length-1)
                    if(mazeSolver[celda.row][celda.column+1] && !visitado[celda.row][celda.column+1]){

                        visitado[celda.row][celda.column+1]=true;
                        Coords empilar = new Coords(celda.row, celda.column+1);
                        if(empilar.column==to.column && empilar.row==to.row){
                            MazeC.add(empilar);
                            encontrado=true;
                            System.out.println("he llegado aqui 4");
                            break;
                        }else{
                            Q.offer(empilar);
                            MazeC.add(empilar);

                        }
                    }
            }

            if(!encontrado) return null;
            else
            return MazeC;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Falta parte del código, que hace la función mazeSolver ?

Comment: Hola Iván y bienvenido! Podrías asegurarte de que el código que expones es correcto? Además sería importante explicar mejor que hace y reducir el código innecesario.

Comment: El código es correcto pero creo que no me explique bien. El enunciado principal es el siguiente: "Por una casilla sólo se puede pasar una vez; y desde una casilla sólo se puede pasar a casillas situadas en la misma fila o en la misma columna." Pero si voy por el camino equivocado, para volver tendria que repetir casilla.

Comment: Es que justamente esa es la "gracia" de la busqueda por anchura, puedes ir avanzando por dos caminos simultaneos, si uno de aquellos caminos no es solución simplemente lo detienes y continuas con los demás caminos que si tienen continuidad hasta que llegues al fin. Eso de devolverse es en la búsqueda por profundidad

Answer (score 2):

Si mal no recuerdo el algoritmo es el siguiente:

```
- posicionarte en la casilla actual 
(*) evaluar si es solución, 
   si es solución: fin
   si no lo es:
      - obtener casillas válidas siguientes
      - preguntar una por una si las casillas validas siguientes son solución
          - si no es solución agregar a lista de camino recorrido
      - por cada casilla siguiente ejecutar (*)
```

Deberías ir avanzando como se muestra en la imagen:

- 1: camino no valido (paredes del laberinto)
- 5: camino recorrido
- 0: camino válido para avanzar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dejo un repositorio en [github](https://github.com/hcarrasc/Maze-Solver) de un laberinto en anchura que programé cuando estudié en la universidad para que le des un miro.

Espero te ayude. saludos